# category text file to php array with explode

Tags: php, database, arrays, insert, text-files

I need to import a large category .txt file to my mysql database. This text file has categories with 3 levels.

My text file look likes the example below (+/- 362 entries):

```
Business
Business = Business Innovation & Ideation = Innovation
Business = Economics
Business = Economics = Global Economics
```

My database table structure:

```
| id | cat | sub_cat | sub_sub_cat |
```

What I want to do, is insert the categories in my database by php. The separator between the cat, sub and sub_sub cat is '='. What I want to reach is a something like a loop to insert this data to my database.

Thanks in advice.

With kind regards,

Nicky

Comment: Would `Business` be its own row with empty sub_cat and empty sub_sub_cat?

Comment: Yes, this would be the head category without a sub or sub_sub :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$lines = file('category.txt'); // slurp file and split into an array by lines

foreach($lines as $line) {
    $parts = explode('=', $line); // decompose a line into individual sections
    $cat = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($parts[0])); // prepare sections for SQL
    $subcat = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($parts[1]));
    $subsubcat = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($parts[2]));

    $sql = "INSERT INTO yourtable (cat, sub-cat, sub_sub_cat) VALUES ('$cat', '$subcat', '$subsubcat');";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Thank u very much! It look likes something is going wrong in my text file cause the insert wasn't good (4/5 entries in one cell of the table and nothing more) but your code looks to be good. I will let you know what's going wrong. Thank u very much

Comment: It's fixed, I had to catch to empty entries and set them to null. Thanks!